# Inheritance issue in javascript. Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, firebase

Here is my code. Don't know how to make in workable.

```
import firebase from "firebase";

export default class database extends firebase{
```

constructor() {

```
super(
      config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyB0y847OMwZQ2BJqz8yQjjWB55YPPUk7lM",
        authDomain: "mytodo-faa53.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://mytodo-faa53.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "mytodo-faa53.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "86914291874"
      },
      fireApp = firebase.initializeApp(config),
      database = fireApp.database(),
      databaseRef = database.ref().child('Todos')
  )

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Place `firebase` in curly braces:

```
import {firebase} from "firebase";
```

You might get another error later on since the `super` function should be used inside the constructor of the inheriting class:

```
export default class database extends firebase {
    constructor() {
       super (
          config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyB0y847OMwZQ2BJqz8yQjjWB55YPPUk7lM",
            authDomain: "mytodo-faa53.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://mytodo-faa53.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "mytodo-faa53.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "86914291874"
          },
          fireApp = firebase.initializeApp(config),
          database = fireApp.database(),
          databaseRef = database.ref().child('Todos')
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: It still the same error: "Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined". I believe it is connected with some inheritance issue i don't know. And thanks for constructor, i was cleaning code uncorrectly)